# Android Studio: device goes mad when plugged in

Tags: android, android-studio

For some reason, when I plug in my Dell Venue with Android Studio opened, the tabled goes mad and start printing tons of messages in Android Console. For example:

```
01-17 18:19:14.013      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 0 coordinate: 0 value: -0.647239 asc->average: -0.319533 noise: -0.327706
01-17 18:19:14.023      483-649/? D/WifiService﹕ releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@21d29c58}
01-17 18:19:14.033      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 0 coordinate: 0 value: -0.647239 asc->average: -0.318716 noise: -0.328523
01-17 18:19:14.033      483-483/? V/AlarmManager﹕ triggered: act=com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT flg=0x14
    Pkg: com.google.android.gms
01-17 18:19:14.053      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 0 coordinate: 0 value: -0.647239 asc->average: -0.311361 noise: -0.335878
01-17 18:19:14.053      483-495/? E/Sensors﹕ pjn=== LightSensor, als_value:80.000000
01-17 18:19:14.073      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 0 coordinate: 0 value: -0.647239 asc->average: -0.299920 noise: -0.347319
01-17 18:19:14.093      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 0 coordinate: 0 value: -0.647239 asc->average: -0.299103 noise: -0.348136
01-17 18:19:14.093     822-1152/? D/GCM﹕ Message class com.google.e.a.a.h
01-17 18:19:14.093     871-1008/? I/GCoreUlr﹕ Successfully inserted location
01-17 18:19:14.093     871-1008/? I/GCoreUlr﹕ Not calling LocationReporter, hasMoved: false, elapsed millis: 847642, request: Stationary(3600000)
01-17 18:19:14.113      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 0 coordinate: 0 value: -0.647239 asc->average: -0.292565 noise: -0.354674
01-17 18:19:14.133      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 0 coordinate: 0 value: -0.647239 asc->average: -0.251704 noise: -0.395535
01-17 18:19:14.153      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 0 coordinate: 0 value: -0.647239 asc->average: -0.239446 noise: -0.407793
01-17 18:19:14.173      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 0 coordinate: 0 value: -0.647239 asc->average: -0.231273 noise: -0.415965
01-17 18:19:14.193      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 1 coordinate: 0 value: -0.460913 asc->average: -0.204305 noise: -0.256607
01-17 18:19:14.213      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 3 coordinate: 2 value: 10.257756 asc->average: 9.976632 noise: 0.281124
01-17 18:19:14.233      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 2 coordinate: 2 value: 10.247949 asc->average: 9.980719 noise: 0.267230
01-17 18:19:14.253      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 2 coordinate: 2 value: 10.247949 asc->average: 9.978267 noise: 0.269682
01-17 18:19:14.273      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 2 coordinate: 2 value: 10.247949 asc->average: 9.957835 noise: 0.290113
01-17 18:19:14.293      483-495/? W/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ Noise too large: asc->index: 2 coordinate: 2 value: 10.247949 asc->average: 9.989707 noise: 0.258242
01-17 18:19:14.313      483-495/? D/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ data z positive
01-17 18:19:14.313      483-495/? D/AccelerometerSimpleCalibration﹕ data z positive had collected
01-17 18:19:14.363      483-530/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ handleMessage: E msg.what=131155
01-17 18:19:14.363      483-530/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ processMsg: ConnectedState
01-17 18:19:14.363      483-530/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ processMsg: L2ConnectedState
01-17 18:19:14.363      483-530/? I/WifiHW﹕ CMD: IFNAME=wlan0 SIGNAL_POLL
01-17 18:19:14.363      563-563/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ RX ctrl_iface - hexdump(len=11): 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c
01-17 18:19:14.363      563-563/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
01-17 18:19:14.383      563-563/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ nl80211: survey data missing!
01-17 18:19:14.383      483-530/? I/WifiHW﹕ REPLY: RSSI=-66
01-17 18:19:14.383      483-530/? I/WifiHW﹕ REPLY: LINKSPEED=52
01-17 18:19:14.383      483-530/? I/WifiHW﹕ REPLY: NOISE=9999
```

This only occurs for some projects.. like them being corrupted. It started happening when I tried to add GL support to one of the projects. May be someone can explain how to fix this?

The program doesn't even run or debugged. Once devices is plugged in, the madness starts.

Answer (score 0):

I too has the same issue re stated the device, it stated working fine.

It is the issue with latest updated google play service.